# create standalone code in GWT

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, gwt

I'm working on a project using among others: GWT, Spring, Hibernate and Bonita (a BPM tool).
Beside the application, I need to create a piece of code to update once in a while the database and update/create workflows.

My question is, how should I create this tool/piece of code so it can

1. use all the java objects available in my application (such as DAOs for instance),
2. update the database,
3. be standalone ?

I am rather new to GWT and completely new to Spring, so any advice is welcome.

Thank you

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is just about the Spring (server-side) objects, then you could just write a class with a main method that creates an ApplicationContext (e.g. a ClassPathXmlApplicationContext) with the beans you need, and then continue from applicationContext.getBean(...)

Or write a simple web API  and interact with that (my favorite approach). A simple Servlet with a little bit of JSON can be enough, or use some REST framework if you like.

If, however, with "all the objects in your application" you really mean all of them (including some client-side-only GWT objects), then one possible approach *might* be to implement a GWTTestCase (you'd have to register your servlets in the module xml then). Generally, I wouldn't use this latter approach - it should always be possible to interact with the server (e.g. update the database) in a clean way without requiring client-side-only classes.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I'm facing a problem: when trying to save an object in DB, flush() crashes: 

javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress.


What configuration is missing here?

Comment: Depends on your Spring configuration. Are you using `@Transactional` annotations? If yes, you'll probably need `<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />`. Read http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-annotations for more info.